# Bring back the chat feed autocomplete!

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

It's just.. cultural. This might be only affecting the morale of the folks in [The 2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595) chatroom, but before that chat system update that somehow changed how autocomplete works, we used to be able to "ping" our lovely questions feed, using the @ notation, and the system would happily autocomplete.

For example:

> @CaptainObvious off-topic.

Or:

> @CaptainObvious well that was fast!

Like I said it might be only cultural.. there's [20 pages of search results in The 2nd Monitor for "@CaptainObvious"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%40CaptainObvious&room=8595), and 16 for "@StackExchange".

We just love talking to our bots.

Please bring back autocomplete for chat feeds!

Comment: Yes, please! *BUT* only if bringing it back doesn't break autocomplete on the mobile version of chat...

Comment: Use the reply feature. If clicking the little arrow is too much work, install the keyboard script.

Comment: @Shog9 what would actually be nice is if the mobile version featured that little arrow. But I guess you're right, we're just somewhat lazy ;)

Comment: @Shog9 I guess it's a programmer thing: when your hands are over the keyboard most of the time, it makes a difference when you have to reach for the mouse to do something. It's a very much noticeable interruption.